# Convert first row as column name in a list of dataframes, then delete first row

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R, and am facing an issue trying to convert the first row of a list of dataframe into the column name.

I have a dataframe of 120 rows, the dput of top 10 rows is given below.

```
> dput(head(mmcmon,10))
structure(list(`mmcall[1:120, ]` = structure(c(121L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 103L, 125L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "0.000120774", 
"0.000411971", "0.000418782", "0.001009412", "0.002133363", "0.006300886", 
"0.007512761", "0.01520653", "0.01922036", "0.02122252", "0.03000229", 
"0.03125497", "0.09864875", "0.1038622", "0.1110728", "0.1716216", 
"0.301216", "0.3091952", "0.3409163", "0.3741058", "0.3840781", 
"0.4457962", "0.554204", "0.6159262", "0.6258942", "0.6590838", 
"0.6908052", "0.6987841", "0.8283813", "0.8889272", "0.8961378", 
"0.9013513", "0.968745", "0.9699977", "0.9787775", "0.9807797", 
"0.9847939", "0.9924875", "0.9936991", "0.9978666", "0.9989906", 
"0.9995812", "0.999588", "0.9998792", "0.9999928", "0.9999952", 
"0.9999953", "0.9999976", "0.9999999", "1", "1.02E-274", "1.06E-170", 
"1.14E-177", "1.33E-08", "1.34E-164", "1.36E-26", "1.50E-67", 
"1.70E-87", "1.74E-137", "1.79E-10", "1.79E-23", "1.80E-220", 
"1.88E-83", "1.92E-09", "1.97E-13", "1.98E-40", "2.13E-69", "2.23E-78", 
"2.37E-08", "2.38E-06", "2.38E-11", "2.55E-74", "2.58E-41", "2.76E-44", 
"2.79E-275", "2.90E-72", "3.06E-56", "3.09E-64", "3.50E-128", 
"3.50E-300", "3.55E-258", "3.61E-95", "3.99E-22", "4.31E-53", 
"4.44E-134", "4.72E-06", "4.84E-06", "5.15E-09", "5.18E-281", 
"5.19E-128", "5.25E-165", "5.34E-66", "5.51E-247", "5.52E-08", 
"5.80E-43", "6.08E-33", "6.14E-46", "6.65E-208", "7.22E-06", 
"7.49E-10", "7.88E-51", "8.24E-130", "8.32E-162", "8.48E-99", 
"8.76E-120", "8.78E-24", "8.81E-28", "9.83E-32", "ABS1,ABS2", 
"ABS1,AR1", "ABS1,AR2", "ABS1,BS", "ABS2,ABS1", 
"ABS2,AR1", "ABS2,AR2", "ABS2,BS", "AR1,ABS1", 
"AR1,ABS2", "AR1,AR2", "AR1,BS", "AR2,ABS1", 
"AR2,ABS2", "AR2,AR1", "AR2,BS", "BS,ABS1", 
"BS,ABS2", "BS,AR1", "BS,AR2"), class = "factor")), .Names = "mmcall[1:120, ]", row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I obtain a list of dataframes by splitting it into 5 dataframes of 24 rows each using the below command:

```
cmonlist=split(mmcmon, (seq(nrow(mmcmon))-1) %/% 24)
```

The dput of first element thus obtained is given below.

> dput(head(cmonlist[[1]]))
>       structure(list(`mmcall[1:120, ]` = structure(c(121L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 103L), .Label = c("0", "0.000120774", "0.000411971", 
>       "0.000418782", "0.001009412", "0.002133363", "0.006300886", "0.007512761", 
>       "0.01520653", "0.01922036", "0.02122252", "0.03000229", "0.03125497", 
>       "0.09864875", "0.1038622", "0.1110728", "0.1716216", "0.301216", 
>       "0.3091952", "0.3409163", "0.3741058", "0.3840781", "0.4457962", 
>       "0.554204", "0.6159262", "0.6258942", "0.6590838", "0.6908052", 
>       "0.6987841", "0.8283813", "0.8889272", "0.8961378", "0.9013513", 
>       "0.968745", "0.9699977", "0.9787775", "0.9807797", "0.9847939", 
>       "0.9924875", "0.9936991", "0.9978666", "0.9989906", "0.9995812", 
>       "0.999588", "0.9998792", "0.9999928", "0.9999952", "0.9999953", 
>       "0.9999976", "0.9999999", "1", "1.02E-274", "1.06E-170", "1.14E-177", 
>       "1.33E-08", "1.34E-164", "1.36E-26", "1.50E-67", "1.70E-87", 
>       "1.74E-137", "1.79E-10", "1.79E-23", "1.80E-220", "1.88E-83", 
>       "1.92E-09", "1.97E-13", "1.98E-40", "2.13E-69", "2.23E-78", "2.37E-08", 
>       "2.38E-06", "2.38E-11", "2.55E-74", "2.58E-41", "2.76E-44", "2.79E-275", 
>       "2.90E-72", "3.06E-56", "3.09E-64", "3.50E-128", "3.50E-300", 
>       "3.55E-258", "3.61E-95", "3.99E-22", "4.31E-53", "4.44E-134", 
>       "4.72E-06", "4.84E-06", "5.15E-09", "5.18E-281", "5.19E-128", 
>       "5.25E-165", "5.34E-66", "5.51E-247", "5.52E-08", "5.80E-43", 
>       "6.08E-33", "6.14E-46", "6.65E-208", "7.22E-06", "7.49E-10", 
>       "7.88E-51", "8.24E-130", "8.32E-162", "8.48E-99", "8.76E-120", 
>       "8.78E-24", "8.81E-28", "9.83E-32", "ABS1,ABS2", "ABS1,AR1", 
>       "ABS1,AR2", "ABS1,BS", "ABS2,ABS1", "ABS2,AR1", 
>       "ABS2,AR2", "ABS2,BS", "AR1,ABS1", "AR1,ABS2", 
>       "AR1,AR2", "AR1,BS", "AR2,ABS1", "AR2,ABS2", 
>       "AR2,AR1", "AR2,BS", "BS,ABS1", "BS,ABS2", 
>       "BS,AR1", "BS,AR2"), class = "factor")), .Names = "mmcall[1:120, ]", row.names = c(NA, 
>   6L), class = "data.frame")

All other dataframes part of the list have similar structures. As you can see, each dataframe name is something like 'mmcall[1:120,]' and the first row is like 'AR1,BS'. I want to rename the column with the first row, and then delete the first row. So I want my dataframe with column name as 'AR1,BS' and the values as 0,0,0,0,8.24E-130.

When I try using lapply, I dont get any error, but get strange result.

> trylist=lapply(cmonlist, function(x) {colnames(x)=x[1,]})

```
> trylist[[1]]
[1] AR1,BS
129 Levels: 0 0.000120774 0.000411971 0.000418782 0.001009412 0.002133363 ... BS,AR2
```

The class of the individual dataframe also gets changed to 'factor'.

```
> class(cmonlist[[1]]) 
[1] "data.frame"
> class(trylist[[1]]) 
[1] "factor"
```

Can anyone please help? I do not understand how to accomplish this and why it gets changed into a factor.

Also, it would be great if someone can also answer why the dput of such a small looking dataframe looks so huge.

Thanks a lot in advance.
-Shivam

Comment: first thing: `colnames` is for matrices, and matrices only allow one type of data, so if you have any letters (you do), all the columns will be converted to strings. use `names`

Comment: @raw - `names` also gives same results I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function inside `lapply` returns `x[1, ]` only. You have to return the whole data frame instead. Use this command:

```
lapply(cmonlist, function(x) "names<-"(x, x[1, ]))
```

If you also want to remove the first row of each data frame, use this:

```
lapply(cmonlist, function(x) tail("names<-"(x, x[1, ]), -1))
```

Comment: `"names<-"(x, x[1, ])` would be equivalent to `names(x) <- names(x[1, ])`, correct? Oh and does this work without back ticks?

Comment: @rawr Almost, it's `names(x) <- x[1, ]`.

Comment: @Sven Your solution works. Thanks a lot!! But as an aside, your comment to `@rawr` actually doesnt work. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: @rawr It does not work without quotation marks, but one could use: `{names(x) <- x[1, ]; x}`.

Comment: @Shivam The command `"names<-"(a, b)` is similar to `names(a) <- b` but leaves `a` unchanged and returns the whole modified object.

Comment: @Sven Thanks Sven, that clarifies.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I was just wondering if it works only with back ticks or also with double quotes or only with double quotes like you are using

Comment: I know that. That's why I was throwing words around like "double quotes"